# Validation message displayed on page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I am new to ASP.NET MVC framework, starting my first project. 
I've used data annotations in my model class for setting validation message. But the validation messages are shown on page load. I want the validation message to be displayed on button click. How can I do this?

Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace final_1.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class TBL_USER
    {
        public int USERID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter user name.")]
        public string USERNAME { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public int ROLE { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter password.")]
        public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CREATED_DATE { get; set; }
        public int STATUS { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Authorize", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.USERNAME, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "User name", @autofocus = "autofocus" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.USERNAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.PASSWORD, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Password" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PASSWORD, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Authorize(TBL_USER userModel)
{
    using (MIEntities db = new MIEntities())
    {
        var userDetails = db.TBL_USER.Where(a => a.USERNAME == userModel.USERNAME && a.PASSWORD == userModel.PASSWORD).FirstOrDefault();
        if (userDetails != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Register", "Student");
        }
        else
        { return View(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code for your controller since it is likely an issue with how the controller is coded.

Comment: @Mocolicious I've added the controller code. Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two action methods for `get` request and for `post` request.

```
[HttpGet] 
        public ActionResult Authorize()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost] 
        public ActionResult Authorize(final.Models.TBL_USER userModel)
        {
            using (LT_LGCDP_MISEntities1 db = new LT_LGCDP_MISEntities1())
            {
                var userDetails = db.TBL_USER.Where(a => a.USERNAME == userModel.USERNAME && a.PASSWORD == userModel.PASSWORD).FirstOrDefault();
                if(userDetails == null)
                {
                    return View(userModel);
                }
                    return RedirectToAction("Register", "Student");
            }
        }
```

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using ModelState to check and then make sure you are returning the ViewModel when you return View.

```
public ActionResult Authorize(TBL_USER userModel)
    {
        using (MIEntities db = new MIEntities())
        {
            var userDetails = db.TBL_USER.Where(a => a.USERNAME == userModel.USERNAME && a.PASSWORD == userModel.PASSWORD).FirstOrDefault();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Register", "Student");
            }
            else
            { return View(userModel); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user4221591 sorry I just realized what you're attempting to do I think.   If you want to check that the password is correct you will have to add some additional code for that check.  What exactly did you attempt to input and what was the result?